# How to monitor Graphql with some SAAS monitoring solution?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, monitoring

I am looking for a good monitoring solution that is also capable of analysing GraphQL queries (out of the box or with little config), can anyone advise something?

My basic needs are:

- See what queries were made
- See the body of the query
- Group queries by type and plot that on the graph

P.S. Instana doesn't work for us because their pricing is more enterprise-oriented.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Datadog or Honeycomb have you looked at those 2 tools. I think they might solve your needs.